# how to create tags in the lists of mailchimp subscriber using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I had created the mail subscription using mailchimp. The mail id is listed in the lists of mailchimp, but i want to pass the firstname,lastname and want to create a tag while doing the mailchimp subscription. but now i am listing only the mail under my list.. when i am trying to create the tag via postman, the tags are created, but i want to add through api code.

```
var mailchimpInstance   = '***',
    listUniqueId        = '*********',
    mailchimpApiKey     = '*****************';

app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
    request
        .post('https://' + mailchimpInstance + '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' + listUniqueId + '/members/')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')
        .set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + new Buffer('any:' + mailchimpApiKey ).toString('base64'))
        .send({
          'email_address': req.body.email,
          'status': 'subscribed',
          'merge_fields': {
            "FNAME": req.body.fname,
            "LNAME": req.body.lname
            }
        })
        .end(function(err, response) {
         if (response.status < 300 || (response.status === 400 && response.body.title === "Member Exists")) {
          res.send('Sign Up Success :)');
          } else {
                res.send('Sign Up Failed :(');
              }
              console.log(req.body.email);
          });

    });
```

This code is for sending the email to the lists..in this code the firstname and lastname is not listed in the lists of mailchimp..and i also need to create tags using this api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a 'tags' body parameter which accepts an array and adds the tags to the mail id.
Here's the documentation: https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#%20

Comment: While links to documentation are a good starting point, you should at least quote the important parts (like examples) in the answer in case the link breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an email address AND add tags, you need to specify the tag as an array in the members field.

This drove me nuts as I noticed it had for a lot of other people reading through Stackoverflow.

In your code, you would add the below when you are calling send.

In the below example, I had already created a tag:

```
var data = {
  status: "active",
  members:[
    {
      tags: ["yourtagname"],
      email_address: email,
      status: "subscribed",
      merge_fields: {
        FNAME: firstName,
        LNAME: lastName,
      },
    }
  ],
}
```